# Fast way of inserting 3 GB data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the fastest way to insert 3GB worth of data in to a table in SQL Server?  I've tried inserting 80,000,000 records using a loop and it took about 2 hours to do.  Is there any quicker way to do such a task?

If you're wondering, this is for benchmarking purposes.

Comment: What is the source of your imports? Another table? A CSV file or another data file? It would help us to understand the context to [edit] your question and include what you currently have.

Comment: check out this answer by  Remus Rusanu and also try exploring Partition switch :https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84164/sql-server-table-insert-performance-optimization

Comment: @rndus2r That question you linked to was about doing it in C#. We do not know what the context is... is he doing this from SQL Server, Java, C# (.NET), another environment still? Until the OP gives us the context, closing for duplicate might give the OP the wrong answer.

Comment: Point given, nevertheless it's a simple google search task.